# Create a schema to check a column isn't null

Tags: json, jsonschema

If I have JSON for a table-like structure that looks something like this:

```
{
"table": {
    "rows": [
        [ 0, null, 1, 2, null ],
        [ null, 1, 2, 3, null ],
        [ 1, 2, 3, null, null ],
        [ null, null, 1, 2, 1 ]
    ]
}
```

I can validate it with a schema like this (note, I'm using draft 3 because that's what my library for validating schema is using, draft 4 might be possible if I go find a different library):

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
    "title": "Table with data",
    "description": "A table with at least 1 row of data with 5 columns per row",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "table" : {
            "description" : "A table",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "rows": {
                    "required" : true,
                    "description": "An array of rows",
                    "type" : "array",
                    "minItems" : 1,
                    "items" : {
                        "type": "array",
                        "minItems": 5,
                        "maxItems": 5
                    }
                }
            },
            "required":true
        }
    }
}
```

This is just checking that we have a `table`, that the `table` has `rows` that `rows` is an array with at least one item. That the rows themselves are arrays and that those arrays have `5` items (columns). This much is easy enough.

What I would like to check is, for each column (`0...4`) there exists *at least* one `row` where the value is *not null*. Is that something that it is possible to express in a json schema? Or is it that beyond what can be done with it.

Comment: If there is a way to define this, it will probably be too complex and not generalizable to any sized matrix (you would have to explicitly define each of the rows or something like that). I think it is preferable to make this sort of validations in the code.